# Парсинг pepsi.ua

Tags: c#, form, синтаксический-анализ

Вот адрес странички http://www.pepsi.ua/codes/new которую мне нужно в форму подставить значения. Проблема в тому что оно мне парсит страничку без формы (возможно проблема у скриптах). Что посоветуете?

Comment: «оно мне парсит страничку без формы». Кто на ком стоял? (ц) Потрудитесь излагать ваши мысли яснее.

Comment: @VladD Под оно наверно имелось ввиду C#?

Comment: @lampa: Похоже на правду. А под «парсит»? Мой гугл не находит в C# функции «парсить страничку».

Comment: Когда заходишь на ссылку показывает форму. Мне нужно эту форму заполнить.Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @alesha-bc: Да как угодно, хоть userscript на greasemonkey. А что вы пробовали, что не получилось? Приведите релевантный код.

Comment: Мне это нужно сделать на c#, я пробовал обычным парсингом, но это не помогло. Как можно сделать с помощью c#?

Comment: @alesha-bc: Что такое «обычный парсинг»? Давайте код, без него непонятно.